# Spark with Mongo DB: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: mongodb, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to load a sample MongoDB collection to Spark using Scala, then save the RDD to a text file. The following is my code:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val mongoConfig = new Configuration()
mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.uri",
      "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB.myCollectionData")

val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
      mongoConfig, // Configuration
      classOf[MongoInputFormat], // InputFormat
      classOf[Object], // Key type
      classOf[BSONObject]) // Value type

documents.map(t => t._1).saveAsTextFile("myMongo")
```

//----------------------------------------------------------

Then I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:55)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil.getMongoClientURI(MongoConfigUtil.java:318)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil.getInputURI(MongoConfigUtil.java:322)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoSplitterFactory.getSplitter(MongoSplitterFactory.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat.getSplits(MongoInputFormat.java:56)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:954)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1290)
```

from this line:

```
documents.map(t => t._1).saveAsTextFile("myMongo")
```

Does anyone have any idea what this error means? Thanks a lot!

Also, below is my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myProject ---
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:jar:2.0.M5b:test
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |              \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9:compile (version selected from constraint [2.2,))
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-datapipeline:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-storagegateway:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpledb:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directconnect:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitosync:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-importexport:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworks:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iam:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.scopt:scopt_2.10:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scalamacros:quasiquotes_2.10:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.twitter:parquet-column:jar:1.6.0rc3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twitter:parquet-common:jar:1.6.0rc3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.twitter:parquet-encoding:jar:1.6.0rc3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.twitter:parquet-generator:jar:1.6.0rc3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.twitter:parquet-hadoop:jar:1.6.0rc3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twitter:parquet-format:jar:2.2.0-rc1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.twitter:parquet-jackson:jar:1.6.0rc3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jodd:jodd-core:jar:3.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-graphx_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jblas:jblas:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.10:jar:0.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.10:jar:0.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.fommil.netlib:core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.f2j:arpack_combined_all:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.rwl:jtransforms:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.spire-math:spire_2.10:jar:0.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.spire-math:spire-macros_2.10:jar:0.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spellchecker:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop:mongo-hadoop-core:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.twitter:chill_2.10:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.10:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO]    +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.1.6:compile
[INFO]    +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.4.5:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-remote_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-actor_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.spark-project.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0-spark:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths:jar:1.2.2a:compile
[INFO]    +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-slf4j_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:compile
[INFO]    +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.mesos:mesos:jar:shaded-protobuf:0.21.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO]    +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-client:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.tachyonproject:tachyon:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.spark-project:pyrolite:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    \- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.8.2.1:compile
```

Comment: Tried this:      val documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
      mongoConfig,  classOf[MongoInputFormat], 
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable])   Then got the error: inferred type arguments [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.bson.BSONObject,com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat] do not conform to method newAPIHadoopRDD's type parameter bounds [K,V,F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]]    any additional change required?

Comment: I am not sure. I'll try to check that later if no one answers before.

Comment: @imagin: I tried what you did in your answer #2, but still same error. Could you please share the spark, mongodb, mongo-hadoop versions you are using? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame : SBT Dependency :  >>>`libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop" % "mongo-hadoop-core" % "1.4.0"` and 
 >>>`libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver" % "3.0.4"`. MongoDB Version : 3.0.7

Comment: Let me know if its working for you?

Comment: @imagin: Thanks for the info. May I ask what's the Spark version you are using? Thanks!

Comment: Spark 1.5.0. This was working for Spark 1.4.1 as well and also Scala version is 2.10.

Comment: works with bson version 3.0.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for imagin's help, here is the final combination of dependencies libraries that works:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a version mismatch between your dependencies. Take a look at your dependency tree and see where the mismatch is happening. The current version of mongo-hadoop-core is using hadoop-* 2.6.0 make sure all your org.apache.hadoop dependencies are using the same version.

Comment: I tried hadoop-* 2.6.0 , the same errors. I added my dependency trees above, I don't see anything wrong myself ... am I missing anything?